# Pyserial dirty data when reading

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I wrote this function to run a separate thread, so I can read from an Arduino continuously. It's supposed to be flexible, so I wanted to make it work for any length of message.

```
    def _readserial(self) -> list:
        received_data = "" # string that I append to
        char = b'' # indivudual bytes of data are read into here
        while self.LINE_BREAK not in char:
            byte = self.read(1)
            char += byte
            # print(char)
        received_data = char.decode('UTF-8', "replace").rstrip("\r")
        # print(received_data)
        current_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return [current_time, received_data]

    def readtobuffer(self):
        try:
            data_list = []
            while True:
                start_time = time.time()
                while (time.time() - start_time <= self.timeout_interval):
                    with self.lock:
                        data_list.append(self._readserial())
                with self.lock:
                    data_to_interpret = data_list.copy()
                    data_list = []
                    self.int_queue.put(data_to_interpret)
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
        finally:
            self.close()
```

The problem is when I test this using an Arduino spitting out a count every millisecond at 9600 baud, the first line is garbage and errors out. Example of data "['2023-08-23 17:23:21', ',�0,0\r\n']"

Should I just make it throw out the first line?

P.S. if there's a better way to do this please inform me

Comment: What is `ord()` on the corrupted character?

Comment: This is coming from an Arduino - are you _sure_ that it's UTF-8?

Comment: You receive a count every millisecond? Over 9600 baud? That's going to be tight.

Comment: When you say the first line, do you mean the first line after the Arduino boots? It's not entirely surprising to get serial garbage under that situation, but it would be difficult to pinpoint the reason. Could be pullup misconfiguration, port misconfiguration, etc.

Comment: @Reinderien ord() gave me 255 on the corrupted char (in the terminal is was '0�0,0' and the bytes were b'0\xff0,0\r\n'" I'm not certain if the Arduino is UTF-8 but the rest of the data after the initial line are perfect. Also, the problem is when the program starts because I've used the Arduino IDE and that works fine.

Comment: @KlausD. I wanted to try an extreme case so I know the program will work. Serial data at 1khz is a little insane at least for my research.

Comment: The method of reading is quite slow, and there are almost certainly better ways to perform line buffering. But it's impossible to say, because `self` is undefined and there isn't enough debugging detail in your question. OS? Version of Pyserial?

Comment: 'self' is really just my reader object which inherits the 'serial.Serial' object but I added these functions and an evaluate function. I've been doing this on Win10, python3.10, and pyeserial3.5. What would be some recommendations to improve performance?